# Access a image dynamically from res folder android

Tags: android, android-image

I have a image in res folder like this

[image]

I want to access this one dynamically like this

```
holder.Viewcover.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("R.id." + CoverimgUrl.get(position)));
```

**CoverimgUrl** is a list which have two image name one is **book_cover** & and another is **blank_image** this array is generated dynamically so how can I set this image from that list

**In One word how to access a image dynamically which is in drawable folder  and I need get that image name from an array list ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Resources res = getResources();
String mDrawableName = "image_name";
int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(resourceId);
icon.setImageDrawable(drawable );
```

Answer (score 1):

First Make **CoverimgUrl** list of integer

```
List<Integer> CoverimgUrl =new ArrayList<Integer>();
            CoverimgUrl.add(R.drawable.book_cover);
            CoverimgUrl.add(R.drawable.blank_image);
```

Then

```
holder.Viewcover.setImageResource(CoverimgUrl.get(position));
```

Answer (score 1):

createFromPath expects a path to the file, not it's ID.

You can use the following:

int id = getResources().getIdentifier(CoverimgUrl.get(position), "id", getPackageName());
holder.Viewcover.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(id));

getIdentifier() gets the ID from the string. When you use the "R" class, it contains static integers for ids. So R.id.some_name is actually an integer, which is the id of the some_name resource.

once you get this integer with getIdentifier, you can use getResources().getDrawable() to get the drawable with the given ID.

Let me know if this works.